# Persistent user variables for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, persistence

I'm building a wordpress website.

My question is:

How can I use (set & get) a persistent variable per user.
For example : I want to give the user a grade, and to keep it.
I cannot keep this data in session, because then when user leaves I will have to start over.

Also, I know I can use cookies, but I prefer to use the server side to keep this information.

Does anyone know a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom user information like this wordpress has some functions that allows you to save the so called "custom meta" for each user. Check this functions in the wordpress codex:

[update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) ->this allows you to store/set the data in the MySql table. So if you want to say give the user a grade you just do:

`update_user_meta( $user_id, "user_grade", "grade_value");`

and wordpress will store the grade for that user.(you can store multiple values, check the codex that I've linked for details...).

[get_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) -> this is used to get the user custom meta, or the data saved by `update_user_meta` as an example that will get the above saved value is:

```
get_user_meta($user_id, "user_grade", true);
```

the last parameter helps you get multiple values, again, check the codex.